# Counting current users viewing a page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito, distributed-computing

I am working on counting number of viewing user on a page. Basically, when a user view an URL `localhost:8080/itemDetail.do?itemId=1`, then the page will showing how many users are viewing on that page at the same time.

**Solution approach**

When user is viewing a particular page, that page will continue to send AJAX request every 1 second back to server, then server will use a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` (both use `ConcurrentHashMap` for the initialization) to contain the `itemId` (to know which page is viewed) and the `IP` and `timeout` count (in the inner `Map`). Every time getting the request, then the counting will increase 1. There is a thread fired during the request process to decrease the timeout counting every 2 seconds. If in the end, the timeout counting is equal to 0, app will consider the user stopped viewing the page, then thread will remove that entry and thus the number of user will be decreased 1. A small problem for this approach is since the timeout number is increasing faster than decreasing, if user open the page long enough and close the page, then the app will take sometime to know that that user already left the page, because the timeout number at that moment is quite big

**Implementation**

```
// Controller

    @RequestMapping(value = AppConstants.ACTION_NUMBER_VIEWING, method = GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public int userItemViewing(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value = "itemId") String itemId) {
        try {
            return eventService.countUserOnline(request, itemId);
        } catch (CAServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error("========== Error when counting number of online user ==========" + e.getMessage());
        }

        return 0;
    }

// Service

private static Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> numberOfCurrentViews;
private Thread countDownOnlineThread;

class OnlineCountingDownRunnable implements Runnable {

    private List<String> timeoutList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private void cleanTimeoutIps() {
        for (String itemId : numberOfCurrentViews.keySet()) {
            Map<String, Integer> currentIps = numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId);

            for(String ip : timeoutList){
                currentIps.remove(ip);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (String itemId : numberOfCurrentViews.keySet()) {
                Map<String, Integer> currentIps = numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId);

                for(String ip : currentIps.keySet()){
                    Integer timeout = new Integer(currentIps.get(ip).intValue() - 1);

                    if (timeout == 0) {
                        timeoutList.add(ip);
                    }

                    currentIps.put(ip, timeout);
                }
            }

            cleanTimeoutIps();

            // counting down time must be double increasing time
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error("---------------- Thread error in counting down online user: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

public int countUserOnline(HttpServletRequest request, String itemId) throws CAServiceException {
    // create a count down timer to detect if the user does not view the page anymore
    String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();

    // init counting down online user map
    if (numberOfCurrentViews == null) {
        numberOfCurrentViews = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
    }

    // start thread to check user online
    if (countDownOnlineThread == null) {
        countDownOnlineThread = new Thread(new OnlineCountingDownRunnable());
        countDownOnlineThread.start();
    }

    LOG.debug("---------------- Requested IP: " + ip);
    if (ip == null || ip.isEmpty()) {
        throw new CAServiceException("======= Cannot detect Ip of the client =======");
    }

    if (numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId) != null) {
        Map<String, Integer> userView = numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId);

        if (userView.get(ip) != null) {
            userView.put(ip, userView.get(ip).intValue() + 1);
        } else {
            userView.put(ip, 1);
        }

        numberOfCurrentViews.put(itemId, userView);
    } else {
        Map<String, Integer> ips = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
        ips.put(ip, 1);

        numberOfCurrentViews.put(itemId, ips);
    }

    LOG.debug(String.format(
        "============= %s is seeing there is %s users viewing item %s =============",
        ip, numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId).size(), itemId
    ));

    return numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId).size();
}
```

**Problems**

I have no idea how to test this functionality since it requires multiple IP addresses to view the page. I have tried to set up JMeter and set up IP spoofing like this [link](http://blog.milamberspace.net/index.php/2009/12/03/changer-ladresse-ip-source-dune-requete-http-lors-dun-test-avec-jmeter-549.html) but was not successful, so I made a small mock test like this to view the log

```
@Test
public void testCountUserOnline() throws Exception {

    List<HttpServletRequest> requests = new ArrayList<HttpServletRequest>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        Mockito.when(request.getRemoteAddr()).thenReturn(String.format("192.168.1.%s", i));
        requests.add(request);
    }

    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new RequestRunnable(requests.get(i)));
        threads.add(thread);
        thread.start();
    }

    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}

class RequestRunnable implements Runnable {
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public RequestRunnable(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10) {
                eventService.countUserOnline(request, "1");
                i++;
                System.out.println(i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

        } catch (CAServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but again, I am not so confident about the implementation

Also, is this the normal way human using to count the number of viewing users on page? I just want to make sure that I don't miss anything in case there is any shortcut for this part. I am using `Spring MVC 3.x`. I need to support IE 9 as well :(((, so `Web Socket` cannot be used extensively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was quite stupid when implementing this at the first time. I should not make the counter based on the thread to make the problem complicated like that. Instead, what I really need is just save the `timestamp` on every request and then, make a thread to compare the current time with the last timestamp of a request on a page. If the time difference is more than a timeout number (10 seconds in this case), then the user already left page and then, I just need to remove that entry from the `Map`.

```
// make it as static, since this needs to be singleton
private static Map<String, Map<String, Date>> numberOfCurrentViews;

// make it as static, since this needs to be singleton
private static Thread cleaningOffLineUserThread;

class OnlineCountingDownRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                for (String itemId : numberOfCurrentViews.keySet()) {
                    Map<String, Date> userView = numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId);

                    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Date>> iterator = userView.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry<String, Date> views = iterator.next();

                        Date lastViewTime = views.getValue();
                        Date currentTime = new Date();
                        long seconds = (currentTime.getTime() - lastViewTime.getTime()) / 1000;

                        if (seconds > TIMEOUT) {
                            iterator.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }

                // make the cleaning worker running every 2 seconds
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error("---------------- Thread error in counting down online user: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

public int countUserOnline(HttpServletRequest request, String itemId) throws CAServiceException {
    // create a count down timer to detect if the user does not view the page anymore
    String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();

    // init counting down online user map
    if (numberOfCurrentViews == null) {
        numberOfCurrentViews = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<String, Date>>();
    }

    // start thread to check user online
    if (cleaningOffLineUserThread == null) {
        cleaningOffLineUserThread = new Thread(new OnlineCountingDownRunnable());
        cleaningOffLineUserThread.start();
    }

    LOG.debug("---------------- Requested IP: " + ip);
    if (ip == null || ip.isEmpty()) {
        throw new CAServiceException("======= Cannot detect Ip of the client =======");
    }

    Map<String, Date> userView;

    if (numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId) != null) {
        userView = numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId);
    } else {
        userView = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Date>();
    }

    userView.put(ip, new Date());
    numberOfCurrentViews.put(itemId, userView);

    LOG.debug(String.format(
        "============= %s is seeing there is %s users, %s viewing item %s =============",
        ip, numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId).size(),
        String.valueOf(numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId).keySet()), itemId
    ));

    return numberOfCurrentViews.get(itemId).size();
}
```

I used the Mock test to test the function and it reflects quite well the result through logs

```
@Test
public void testCountUserOnline() throws Exception {

    List<HttpServletRequest> requests = new ArrayList<HttpServletRequest>();

    HttpServletRequest request1 = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletRequest request2 = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletRequest request3 = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);

    Mockito.when(request1.getRemoteAddr()).thenReturn(String.format("192.168.1.%s", 1));
    Mockito.when(request2.getRemoteAddr()).thenReturn(String.format("192.168.1.%s", 2));
    Mockito.when(request3.getRemoteAddr()).thenReturn(String.format("192.168.1.%s", 3));

    requests.add(request1);
    requests.add(request2);
    requests.add(request3);

    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new RequestRunnable(request1, 50, "1", "2"));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new RequestRunnable(request2, 20, "1", "3"));
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(new RequestRunnable(request3, 10, "3", "1"));

    threads.add(thread1);
    threads.add(thread2);
    threads.add(thread3);


    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        thread.start();
    }

    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}

class RequestRunnable implements Runnable {
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private String [] pageSet;
    private int duration;


    public RequestRunnable(HttpServletRequest request, int duration, String ... pageSet) {
        this.request = request;
        this.pageSet = pageSet;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            int i = 0;
            while(i < duration) {
                i ++;
                for (String page : pageSet) {
                    eventService.countUserOnline(request, page);
                }

                LOG.debug("Second " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

        } catch (CAServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Apache Benchmarking tool ?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html